# openpop, get the mail adress of the receiver (my email)

Tags: asp.net, email, pop3, openpop

I am trying to create a small web based mail client and I am using openpop to connect to the mail server, to download all new emails at the server.
But I can't get the email of the receiver of the mail(my emailaddress).
The mail I am connecting to is a "catch-all" account. So there are many different email addresses used when emailing me. (500 of them)

I've tried using this:

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message newMessage;
....
newMessage = client.GetMessage(i);
....
string mailA = newMessage.Headers.To.ToString();
```

But the output is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OpenPop.Mime.Header.RfcMailAddress]
```

I guess that the problem is that I am trying to convert an object to a string.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string mailto = "";
foreach (RfcMailAddress mailId in loadedMessage.Headers.To)
{
    mailto += mailId.MailAddress.ToString() + "; ";
}
```

This should give mail addresses in a string with a ; as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I was able to solve it:

```
string emailA = "";

        foreach (OpenPop.Mime.Header.RfcMailAddress objectItem in newMessage.Headers.To)
        {
            emailA = objectItem.Address.ToString();
        }
```

A bit dirty This code doens't take care of multiple receivers.